# React native start an mp4 video on the native player

Tags: android, react-native, video, video-streaming, expo

Is there a way using snack.expo.io as proof, to be able to start an mp4 video on the native player?

I have the following video: [Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4)

There is a way to start the device's native player.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `Video` inside the expo.

This is the `snack`  link to `Video`.

[this link](https://snack.expo.io/HkFjpyhhW)

If you insert the link in `uri`, it will play .

example.js

```js
import { Video } from 'expo';
...
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
...
```

[A link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/) that details video.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this thing too.
But what would I like to know there is a way to be able to recall the native player of the device in use?

Each device inside contains a native player to read video files.

I wanted to know if there is a way and through expo you can do it.

Comment: Are you asking me if I can read the video player on  phone in expo?

Comment: I don't know how to use a video player installed on my phone.